# Setup Sitecore MVP website in Sitecore 10.2

Tags: docker

I am trying to set up `MVP-Site` website in `Sitecore 10.2 with Docker` from this `Github` url https://github.com/Sitecore/MVP-Site/tree/feature/start-env-script and I am facing the below issue:

[image]

Comment: The most common reason for this is that you have IIS running on your machine. Run “iisreset stop”. Compose down the containers and then compose up and try again.

Comment: @jrap I tried this but it is not working

Comment: have you gone through article from one of the MVP related to this site setup, check this out it may help you: https://navansitecorenotes.blogspot.com/2021/12/how-to-setup-sitecore-102-mvp-site.html

Comment: @RinkuJain yes I checked this one as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are points I have tried:

1. Run `clean.ps1` inside docker\clear.ps1
2. Deleted my docker containers
3. Again run this command `.\Start-Environment -LicensePath "C:\path\to\license.xml"`
4. Still I was getting the same error
5. Then I run `.\Start-Environment.ps1 -InitializeEnvFile` again and again, I think 2-3 times then after that `Sitecore-MVP` site has been set up successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for MVP site setup can be found in README.md in the [MVP Site Github Repo](https://github.com/Sitecore/MVP-Site).

In short, the steps are:

1. create valid certificate for `*.sc.localhost`
2. update .env file with values for your setup
3. run `.\init.ps1 -InitEnv -LicenseXmlPath "C:\path\to\license.xml" -AdminPassword "DesiredAdminPassword"`. Replace values valid for your solution.
4. run `.\up.ps1`

During setup you will be notified to accept device authorization and provide admin credentials.